# Crystal reports uses PreviousValue What is the equivalent in Jasper reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, jasper-reports

Crystal reports uses PreviousValue (fld) What is the equivalent in Jasper reports?

I have searched online for possible answers but as yet not found anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to get the previous value of a field in JasperReports, but it can be done using two variables like this (the variable `class` should match the field type):

```
<variable name="PreviousFldValue" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{CurrentFldValue}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
<variable name="CurrentFldValue" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{fld}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

You would then use `$V{PreviousFldValue}` as the previous value of the field.

Note that the order in which the variables are declared is important, the solution relies on `PreviousFldValue` being calculated before `CurrentFldValue`.